# My CNN regression predicts the same output for different inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I was creating a CNN for prediction of the activity of some molecules. But while I train my data, they give the same prediction whatever I do. I made the linear layers deeper, I changed the learning rate and batches, I even tried to train the network one molecule at a time but also the same. I made sure that the dimensions are matched between the data and the prediction but it always give the same values (as if it only picks one value of the labels to train the whole data set on.)

```
class Net(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)  # (input, features, kernel)
       # that kernel size is the best as it gives highest features
       self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
       self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5)
       
       x = torch.randn(267, 56).view(-1, 1, 267, 56)
       self._to_linear = None
       # generate a dummy array where our
       # /values to be flattened will be introduced inside
       self.convs(x)
       # Pooling and flattening to prepare for the linear network
       # Linear function
       
       self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 5000)  # flattening
       self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5000, 1000)
       self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1000, 500)
       self.fc4 = nn.Linear(500, 256)
       self.fc5 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
       self.fc6 = nn.Linear(128, 32)
       self.fc7 = nn.Linear(32, 1)

   def convs(self, x):
       # Max pooling over 3x3
       x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
       x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2, 2))
       x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), (2, 2))
       if self._to_linear is None:
           self._to_linear = x[0].shape[0]*x[0].shape[1]*x[0].shape[2]
       return x

   def forward(self, x):
       x = self.convs(x)
       x = x.view(-1, self._to_linear)
       # .view is reshape ... this flattens X before
       x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
       x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
       x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
       x = F.relu(self.fc4(x))
       x = F.relu(self.fc5(x))
       x = F.relu(self.fc6(x))
       x = self.fc7(x)
       # bc this is our output layer. No activation here.
       return x 


net = Net()
print(net)

# Optimizer and Loss Function
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()

epochs = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 100
if torch.cuda.is_available(): #gpu adapted
   net1.cuda()

for epoch in range(epochs):# Converting inputs and labels to Variable (first 50)
   for i in tqdm(range(0, len(x_trial), BATCH_SIZE)):
       if torch.cuda.is_available():
           inputs = Variable(x_inp.cuda())
           labels = Variable(y_inp.cuda())
       else:
           inputs = Variable(x_trial[i:i+BATCH_SIZE])
           labels = Variable(y_trial[i:i+BATCH_SIZE])

       # Clear gradient buffers
       optimizer.zero_grad()

       # get output from the model, given the inputs
       outputs = net(inputs)

       # get loss for the predicted output
       loss = loss_function(outputs, labels)
       print(loss)
       # get gradients w.r.t to parameters
       loss.backward()

       # update parameters
       optimizer.step()

   print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))

#The prediction is something like that :-
tensor([[6.1313],
       [6.1313],
       [6.1313],
       ...,
       [6.1313],
       [6.1313],
       [6.1313]])
```

credits in learning and the model to https://pythonprogramming.net/convnet-model-deep-learning-neural-network-pytorch/

Anyone could help?